# Git flow to work with troubled development method

Tags: git

I am having a hard time coming up with a GIT process flow that works with my companies development method.  I've never worked with another software company, so I'm not sure how different our method is compared to others.

We have 50 different systems that we create--each basically doing the same thing, but customized for the customer's business rules, rating versions (we create insurance policy tracking systems), etc.  A developer is assigned to a team (of a total of 5 developers) that has access to about 15 of these systems--and they could easily do changes in each of those 15 systems in any given week.  We have support and smaller development work that is integrated into the live system weekly on an "as needed" basis--in other words, there is nothing outlined as included with the "next release"--the next release is whatever we get done to go live next week.  In addition, we have major development that has designated due dates.  These due dates are dictated by state approval and 3rd party vendor releases in addition to the "we just didn't get it done in time" scenario that seems to plague us.

In essence, on any given week, we could post minor support / development tickets AND major development tickets to production--none of these tickets having a solid release date when the tickets are initially created.

We've been using front page extensions, but we really need to move to the present.  Is there a git flow that will work to accommodate this development method?  Would a different version control system work better?

Comment: Honestly I think I've done this at various firms using SCCS, SVN, Clearcase and git. Although I'd personally plump for git, I think the real constraint is how you choose to manage QA, UAT and customer releases. Perhaps you could describe that?

Answer (score 1):

If scheduled and weekly releases share common codebase (i.e you have single development mainline and one supported version per system) you can use "Branch per task" idea and [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) as implementation of idea.

> Would a different version control system work better?

It's (mostly) a question of personal tastes and preferences

Comment: We are currently using the "branch per task" idea and Git flow, but I'm wondering how difficult that is going to be keeping up with all these branches.

Comment: We have three branches that are tied to servers--a QA branch, a Support branch (for UAT), a Staging branch (for cycle testing), and a Master branch (tied to live/production).  We have a release branch (that is weekly copied from QA) that is used as a single development mainline for developer testing and collaboration.  Anything that will be going to QA within the next week gets posted to this branch upon completion.

Comment: The project Lead is in charge of maintaining this branch.  Once promoted, a new release should be created for any new work.   We have support / minor development work that is done on individual task branches--these branches can be merged into the release branch if they aren't dire to production, or merged into live (for severity one issues) at the same time that they are merged into the other branches.

Comment: Major development work (that involves multiple developers to collaborate but may not be included in a release for several weeks) has a milestone / effort branch created--it is maintained by a lead of that particular effort.  we send an email out once we push changes to github (on these milestone branches), so everyone can update their local branch.  I'm just worried that this is a lot to keep up with and that developers are spending more time keeping up with changes than actually developing...I don't think we have a personal preference--we don't have a knowledge base as to what would work best

Answer (score 0):

### Separate Things That Change

> We have 50 different systems that we create--each basically doing the same thing, but customized for the customer's business rules, rating versions (we create insurance policy tracking systems), etc.

The problem is neither Git nor your workflow. The problem, as far as I can tell, is that you have a sub-section of your code that is highly variant, and you are making changes to your core application rather than to a submodule or external resource.

As a rule of thumb, the easiest way to resolve this sort of problem is to separate out the things that change (e.g. your business rules) into a separately-managed resource. How you manage that resource is up to you, but [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or [Puppet node definitions](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_node_definitions.html) are two reasonable options.

### Resource Files and Modules

You might also consider:

1. Refactoring your variant code as a YAML, JSON, INI, or other resource file that is read in at run-time.
2. A set of code files (e.g. Ruby modules) appropriate to your application that can be conditionally included at compile-time or run-time.

Again, the point of doing these things is to extract the stuff that changes, separating it from the application logic that is loaded for everyone. A lot depends on your application's language and its architecture; there's no single "right answer" here.

Comment: This is actually what I've been pushing to get done; however, to do so would be very expensive and time consuming.  While I think this is the best idea, I don't think that it's an option that I will be able to use